# refresh data in windows form application

Tags: c#, winforms, rest, asynchronous

I cannot figure out how to google this. I have found information about setting handling a button click request, but I cannot find any information about how to refresh the data of my app on a set time interval. I am a beginner with windows forms so I am trying to learn more about it.

I am building a weather application and I have a client that is fetching data from openWeatherMap's rest api. I am just not sure how to set up my form to display this and refresh it every say 10 min. Can someone give me some examples/resources?

Comment: Things I have looked at that maybe someone could add to:

Comment: Are you just looking for something like a `Timer` object?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/index and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt620013.aspx

Comment: @ClintonCochrane - Timer is one of many potential correct answers.  SO isn't intended to be a coder for hire type website.  I see that was mentioned and you still are  unsure of the approach.  You will need to do some research to see how to implement a total solution given your situation.  I recommend changing your approach.  The fact that you want to refresh data on a timer is a code smell. Consider asynchronous approaches that do not block the UI.  And consider a push approach to data (as opposed to polling on a timer).  Google polling vs push

Comment: I would prefer an async approach. If you have some resources or some way to phrase a search so I can get on the right track that would be great.

Comment: There are websites with specific answers to specific questions like SO.  Then there are sites with complete code examples (not SO).  Google "winforms push notifications". I ran the search and immediately came up with an app example:  https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/pandeypradip/testing-of-push-notification-using-windows-form-application/

Comment: perhaps I am just really confused. I don't think I can push data from the server since I do not run it. I am making a request to the api provided by openWeatherMap. I am just creating a client to consume the data.

Comment: In that case use the Timer class as mentioned.  Yes run it on a non-UI thread so you don't block the UI.  Blocking the UI makes the app appear frozen which is of course a bad user experience.  I recommend googling async/await for C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking to use something like the [Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer?view=netframework-4.7.2) class.

Comment: kind of. I was looking that that, but I am just not sure how to actually set it up in my form. Like do I make my Load a void async call and just set the timer there? Or what.

Comment: The example in the link is self-explanatory, it creates a timer and every 5 seconds it raises a MessageBox. Just do something similar but instead retrieve your data and update your controls with the new data.

Answer (score 0):

Read about [System.Windows.Forms.Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer.tick) class and his [Tick event](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer.tick).

Comment: would this go in the form load or would I put this in the method that actually does the calling and just call that from the form load

Comment: Yes, you can initialize Timer starting time after your form appearance by his [Start() method](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer.start).